# Assigning a string to a char* variable

Tags: c, string, char

A code I am reviewing uses following string assignment

```
char *str;
str ="";
```

The coder then uses this 'str' to temporarily hold a string like.

```
str = "This is a message";
fwrite(str, 1 ,strlen(str), fp);
```

Then this str is used again at some other place to assign a new string with a similar use.

I know that this works, I want to find out how exactly does this work.
How can you declare a `char` pointer and make it point to a string like that?
What could be the maximum string length such a pointer can hold?
Where is this string stored? Is it automatically `malloc`'d?

Comment: That last code snippet doesn't compile.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited it out. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: @SteveH the last code was important from the point of view of concept,no need of being sorry and edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer doesn't "hold" a string, it just points to where the original string is located. In this case the string literal is kept as part of the program and the pointer is set to it; when you reassign the pointer, you're not making any copies, just setting the pointer to a different address.

The maximum size of the string is thus the maximum size of a string literal, which will depend on the compiler and the amount of available program space.

If you want to actually make a copy of a string, first you must allocate some storage for it which must be one greater than the number of characters. Then use `strcpy` to make the copy.

Comment: So where is this string stored in the memory? Heap?
Can there be an extreme case where I assign a very long string and cause some exception?
When I assign a new string, does the original string stay on (assuming heap) like a garbage?

Comment: @SteveH, string literals are generally kept alongside the code itself, not on the heap or the stack.

Answer (score 1):

This string is statically contained in the object module. You don't need to malloc memory for such strings, because they already have a memory assigned by the compiler. Because of this, you also can not free such a pointer. If you look with an hex editor in your exe file, you can see that such a string is contained inside it, as opposed to a dynamically allocated string, which only exists in memory as long as the executable runs.

The maximum size of such a string depends on your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

`char*` is just a pointer to a char (or series of them).

You can have it pointing to any "string" you like. In the examples given, they are just changing the pointer's value (i.e. what `str` points to).

Answer (score 0):

> `char *name;`
>
> `name="some string";`//the `name` points to the address of location of
> the string.

is not similar to :

> char str[];
>
> str="some string";// remember this type of statement
> won't work,because str is about to store characters but you are
> assigning the pointer.

A constant character string always represents a pointer to that string.